# How to pass object with string type field to arraylist

Tags: java, arrays, oop, arraylist

```
public class NewClass {
    ArrayList<stu> m = new ArrayList<>();
    private Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    public void add(){
        int id = sc.nextInt();
        sc.next();
        String name = sc.nextLine();
        m.add(new stu(id, name));
    }
    public void printList(){
        for(stu i : m){
            System.out.println(i.getId() +" "+i.getName());
        }
    }
}
```

stu class have id is number and name is String.
The 'id' variable is passed to the arraylist but the 'name' variable cannot.
I hope someone can show me how to fix it

Comment: java is not javascript

Comment: What is the error message? Or what is printed instead of expected output?

Comment: Ex:  m.add(new stu(12,"Peter"));
But "Peter" cannot cannot transmit to m. It only prints 12